# Why remote branches are shown as tracked, even though they are not tracked locally?

Tags: git

I recently cloned from this remote repository.
https://github.com/dave-githubber/my-first-github-repository

Right after i cloned it, i did:

```
(base) hakan@hakan-VirtualBox:~/CompleteGitGuide/temp/my-first-github-repository$ git show-ref
1fd2ddb6f29becd8d3f3148271e230490d424f85 refs/heads/main
1fd2ddb6f29becd8d3f3148271e230490d424f85 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
a45b41988603994aac1292ff086ba913567276e2 refs/remotes/origin/feature-1
1a6fd0202b24acb790e52a9a4dba4a26cc94a39a refs/remotes/origin/feature-2
1fd2ddb6f29becd8d3f3148271e230490d424f85 refs/remotes/origin/main
1fd2ddb6f29becd8d3f3148271e230490d424f85 refs/remotes/origin/temp
```

Note that there is only one tracking main branch:

```
(base) hakan@hakan-VirtualBox:~/CompleteGitGuide/temp/my-first-github-repository$ git branch -vv
* main 1fd2ddb [origin/main] Create hello-github.txt
```

However, when i do git remote show origin , it says that feature-1, feature-2 and temp branches are also tracked:

```
(base) hakan@hakan-VirtualBox:~/CompleteGitGuide/temp/my-first-github-repository$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/dave-githubber/my-first-github-repository.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/dave-githubber/my-first-github-repository.git
  HEAD branch: main
  Remote branches:
    feature-1 tracked     <<< why?
    feature-2 tracked     <<< why?
    main      tracked
    temp      tracked     <<< why?
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    main merges with remote main
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    main pushes to main (up to date)
```

Can you explain why  `feature-1`, `feature-2` and `temp` branches are shown as tracked locally?

Comment: What is the output `git branch -a`?

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

This just means that your Git has, and is updating, `origin/feature-1`, `origin/feature-2`, and `origin/temp`.

(It's also yet another example of how Git badly overloads various terms, like "remote", "tracking", and "branch".  Compare an *untracked file* to a *tracked branch* and to the `git branch --set-upstream-to` option.  In the bad old days, instead of saying that `master` had `origin/master` as its upstream, we would say that `master` "tracked" `origin/master`.  Meanwhile `origin/master` is a remote-tracking name, or remote-tracking branch name ... which has nothing to do with tracked vs untracked files.)

#### Long

The `git remote` command is an odd one.  To see why, let's look at some other commands first.

Most Git commands operate purely locally.  The big two exceptions are `git fetch`, which obtains (some or all of their) commits from some *other* Git repository, and `git push`, which sends (some or all of your) commits *to* some other Git repository.  A third exception, `git ls-remote`, consists of running the very first part of `git fetch`—calling up another Git repository—and then just printing out the information that `git fetch` would get *from* that repository, showing their branch and tag names, for instance.

The `git pull` command just runs `git fetch` first, then uses a second Git command that operates locally—normally `git merge`, but you can configure it to use `git rebase` instead—to *incorporate* the commits that `git fetch` just fetched.  So, while `pull` does contact some other Git, it only does so because it starts with `fetch`.

The three commands that definitely contact some other Git usually do so with a *remote*, which is a short name like `origin`.  This short name is used as part of a key in a key-value pair, so that your Git can get the correct URL at which to call up that other Git.

It's temping to think of *all* other Git commands as operating only locally.  But for the `git remote` command, this is only half right:

- `git remote add`, `git remote remove`, and `git remote set-url` are all purely local operations.  Note that these add or remove a remote like `origin`, or—`set-url`—change the stored URL.
- `git remote update` is mostly a funny way to spell `git fetch`; `git remote prune` is sort of a funny way to spell `git fetch --prune`; and `git remote set-head` *can* (but does not always) invoke the same code as `git ls-remote`: when using `git remote set-head --auto`, your Git has to figure out what *their* Git has as their `HEAD`, which means calling up their Git and asking them.
- `git remote show` contacts the remote if you *don't* use the `-n` option.  Like the others, it uses the same code that `git ls-remote` or `git remote set-head` would use, here, to ask the other Git about its various branch names.  With `-n`, it *doesn't* do that, and just looks at your (local) *remote-tracking* names.

Some of this stuff *predates the invention of remotes*.  Before Git had remotes, like `origin`, you had to type in the full URL every time.  This was terrible.<sup>1</sup>  So people tried several options to get around this.  Only one of them worked really well, but Git today still supports several others; you'll see these described in the [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) and [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) documentation.

When the concept of *remotes* was invented, though—short names like `origin` that can hold the URL—Git grew the notion of *remote-tracking names*.<sup>2</sup>  These let your Git **remember** *their* Git's `main`, `develop`, `feature-1`, and so on.  The way we use them is simple and clean: our Git creates or updates our `origin/main` from their `main` because we ran `git fetch origin`.  If our Git saw that they had, at that time, `feature-1`, our Git creates or updates our `origin/feature-1` too.  The precise details here changed over time,<sup>3</sup> but in modern Git, we have these remote-tracking names.  All we have to do to update them is run `git fetch`.<sup>4</sup>

You can, however, choose *not* to have your own Git repository keep track of all of their (`origin`'s) branches.  If you like, you can set up a so-called *single branch* clone.  Here, you pick some branch on `origin` that you want your Git to copy to `origin/whatever`:

- You can do this at `git clone` time with the `--single-branch` option.
- Or, you can do this at `git remote add` time with the `-t` option.

You can update which branch(es) you have your Git copy to remote-tracking names with `git remote set-branches`.  This way, you can set things up to "track" (as in, create remote-tracking names for) *two* branches, instead of just one.

The `git remote show` command will either read their branch names (no `-n`: `git remote show` runs `git ls-remote` internally) or guess at their branch names (`-n`), and will tell you which of their branch names you're having your Git copy to remote-tracking names.  This is what it means when it says `tracked`.

---

<sup>1</sup>To see why, try typing in the full URL every time.  It gets tiring, and the opportunities for typos are huge.

<sup>2</sup>The Git documentation calls these *remote-tracking branch names*.  I find that the word *branch* here just clutters this up.  They're not *branch* names in your repository, in that `git switch` won't switch to them, for instance; you have to use `git switch --detach` and you'll end up with a detached HEAD.  This is all fine, but goes to show that the name is not a *branch* name, so it makes sense not to *call* it one either.

<sup>3</sup>Before Git version 1.8.4, some kinds of `git fetch` didn't bother updating *any* remote-tracking names at all.  Some Linux distributions still ship with these ancient versions of Git.  Use `git --version` to find out which version you have.

<sup>4</sup>There's one hitch with these remote-tracking names.  Suppose `origin` has a temporary branch name, like `temp`.  You run `git fetch origin` (or just `git fetch`, which fetches from `origin`) and you get `origin/temp` in your repository.

Then—a minute later, or next week, or whatever—whoever controls `origin` *deletes* their `temp` branch.  You run `git fetch` again; your Git calls up `origin` and finds the `main` branch, but no `temp` branch.  So your Git updates your `origin/main` ... but *does nothing with your `origin/temp`*.  They don't *have* one, so there is no need to update *yours*.

This leaves you with a *stale* `origin/temp`.  It's just leftover junk.  You can delete it manually, or you can run `git fetch --prune origin`, or `git remote prune origin`.  Your Git will call up their Git, look at their branch names, see that they *don't* have a `temp`, see that you *do* have an `origin/temp`, and clear out the leftover junk.

Or, you can set `fetch.prune` to `true` in your configuration.  I do it in my per-user global one:

```
git config --global fetch.prune true
```

This makes every `git fetch` act like `git fetch --prune`, automatically, to clean out the deadwood remote-tracking names.

This *probably should be* Git's default, but Git is still mostly compatible with Git version 1.7, and Git version 1.7 doesn't do that, so modern Git still doesn't.